# How to programmatically set the WPF Toolkit DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker

I can't believe there is not a single sample for the xceed WPF toolkit datetime picker. All there is are code snippets which is useless for newbies like me.

I have declared my datetimepicker as follows:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="dpFromAT" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  ></xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

now all I want to do , is to set the value displayed when I launch my program.
i have tried the following code during on loaded event but none works:

```
dpFromAT.DefaultValue = (DateTime?)CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendFrom;
dpFromAT.Value = (DateTime?)CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendFrom;
dpToAT.DefaultValue = (DateTime?)CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendTo;
dpToAT.Value = (DateTime?)CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendTo;
```

Comment: I have tried in my project and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimePicker has **Value** property since there's no other property with type DateTime.Bind that property with XAML and its get automatically updated when page is loaded

code snippet:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding todayDate}"></xctk:DateTimePicker>

private DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Today;
        public DateTime todayDate
        {
            get
            {
                return todayDate
            }
            set
            {
                  todayDate = value;
             }
          }
```

Comment: Thanks i've tried this but, it doesn't work. I did the binding but when I do the following : 'dpFromDT = CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendFrom;' it doesn't get update

Comment: don't create any instance or referring a name of the control. just update the value in a property and it will get automatically updated. just try this as todayDate = CUtilities.VisibleChartTrendFrom;

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.. Don't worry about it, I've decided to dump the stupid xceed DateTimePicker